# Why iOS6 can't play some mp4 video files?

Tags: ios6, html5-video, mp4

I have a mp4 video that plays properly on iOS5 but not on iOS6. Here is a direct link to video for testing:

http://www.wordcafe.de/videos/test.mp4

All other videos in the website work on iOS6 and only this particular one can't be played on iOS6. I thought the problem is with my HTML5 video player, but then I saw that even a direct link to video as pasted above doesn't work. On my iPodTouch iOS6 I see the play icon crossed out by a diagonal line. Does anybody know why and how this problem can be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the field order to progressive. [Found on Apple Support communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4367075?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: How? Is there any open-source tool or a web-based tool that allows me do that?

Comment: I exported the video with [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) and even though I couldn't find any settings for field order the new video works!

Comment: Using HandBrake ios6 is able to read the mp4, but ios5 no longer read the new mp4. Did you fixed it ?